# Error "misplaced \noalign \hline" in tabular with {>centering}p{width}

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I don't understand why adding a content to the last cell in combination with the centering option produces a "misplaced \noalign \hline" error. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \noindent This works:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{0.02\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.1\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.33\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            $n$ & $x_n$ & $f(x_n)$ & $f'(x_n)$ & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    This too:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.02\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.33\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            $n$ & $x_n$ & $f(x_n)$ & $f'(x_n)$ & $x_{n+1}$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    But this gives a "misplaced \verb|\noalign| \verb|\hline|" error and an overfull \verb|\hbox|:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{0.02\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.1\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.33\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            $n$ & $x_n$ & $f(x_n)$ & $f'(x_n)$ & $x_{n+1}$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: use `\centering\arraybackslash` at least on the last column (I usually use it on all). `\centering` alters the meaning of ``\\`` (which has special meaning in tables) and `\arraybackslash` returns ``\\`` to its tabular definition.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've tried to place `\arraynewline` both before and after `\\\` but it didn't work.

Comment: sorry typo: I meant `\tabularnewline`  use that _instead_ of `\\ ` not before or after it.

Answer (score 2):

As proposed by daleif and David Carlisle, adding `\centering\arraybackslash` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{0.02\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.1\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.33\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            $n$ & $x_n$ & $f(x_n)$ & $f'(x_n)$ & $x_{n+1}$ \centering\arraybackslash\\ 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here's another solution by David Carlisle:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{0.02\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.1\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.33\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            $n$ & $x_n$ & $f(x_n)$ & $f'(x_n)$ & $x_{n+1}$ \tabularnewline 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, I defined a new column type `A` based on the assumptions that all cells only contain contents in math mode and that the table should be exactly as wide as the textwidth:

(Red lines indicate margins)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{\(}wc{\dimexpr #1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.2\arrayrulewidth}<{\)}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{ | A{0.1} | A{0.1} | A{0.4} | A{0.2} | A{0.2} | }
            \hline
            n & x_n & f(x_n) & f'(x_n) & x_{n+1} \\ 
            \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied your code into texstudio and it compiled with many errors. Here's the first one:
line 10: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (w): `c' used. ...1} | A{0.1} | A{0.4} | A{0.2} | A{0.2} | }

Comment: Which version of the `array` package do you use? The `w` column type was introduced in version 2.4f.

Comment: I've just checked. It's 2.4d.

Comment: In order to get rid of the error message, update your packages.